# Speech recognition, batch processing, speech analytics, 404 [No such child resource]

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I use the following url to access IBM's speech recognition batch processing via curl:

"https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/v1/batches?function=recognize&timestamps=true&audio_metrics=true&model=en-US_NarrowbandModel&speech_analytics=true"

The files are in a COS bucket at us-geo.  I get the following response:

{
      "error": "No such child resource.",
      "code": 404,
      "code_description": "No Such Resource"
}

Any suggestions as to what resource is being referred to?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Cheers, Scott

Answer (score 0):

The API signature that you are attempting to use matches the speech to text : customer care API, that according to the documentation at

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text-icp

> The Speech to Text: Customer Care service is an on-premise solution
>   that is available only on IBM Cloud Private.

If that doesn't match your usage then the API you are attempting will not work.

If on the other hand it does match your usage then you need to submit a multi-part form with information locating the COS bucket holding your audio files.

EG.

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --form input_credentials_file=@my_cos_credentials.json --form input_bucket_location=us-geo --form input_bucket_name=my_cos_input_bucket --form output_credentials_file=@my_cos_credentials.json --form output_bucket_location=us-geo --form output_bucket_name=my_cos_output_bucket "https://{icp_cluster_host}{:port}/speech-to-text/api/v1/batches?function=recognize&speech_analytics=true"
```